# maprlogin java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError com.mapr.security.JNISecurity.SetParsingDone()

Tags: java, hadoop, mapr

For many days this below maprclient tool was working on my windows machine
Suddenly got a problem of UnsatisfiedLinkError

What could be fix to the below issue

C:\Opt\mapr-client-5.2.2.4\bin>maprlogin.bat password -user pimbdu_t

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Djava.vendor="Sun Microsystems Inc."
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.mapr.security.JNISecurity.SetParsingDone()V
        at com.mapr.security.JNISecurity.SetParsingDone(Native Method)
        at com.mapr.baseutils.cldbutils.CLDBRpcCommonUtils.init(CLDBRpcCommonUtils.java:222)
        at com.mapr.baseutils.cldbutils.CLDBRpcCommonUtils.<init>(CLDBRpcCommonUtils.java:72)
        at com.mapr.baseutils.cldbutils.CLDBRpcCommonUtils.<clinit>(CLDBRpcCommonUtils.java:63)
        at com.mapr.login.MapRLogin.main(MapRLogin.java:433)

C:\Opt\mapr-client-5.2.2.4\bin>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there has been a change either to your client or the application MAPR. This is what you generally see when your local client and the central cluster are not in sync.

You can simply copy the \lib folder from the edge node and copy it to your local /opt/mapr/lib. This should solve the issues.